# Infinite Loop? Can't see why

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that takes in a `roleID(as an int)`, and compares it to a multidimensional array to see if that array contains that `roleID`. if it does, it sets a bool to true and breaks. if it doesn't, the loop never exits. I'm hoping this is something stupid that I'm overlooking, but I've had a few different people look it over now.

The size of the `userRoles array` that I am testing with right now is `3`. I can print `userRoles.GetLength(0)` and it says 3, and that matches whats in the database.

here's the code:

```
public bool IsInRole(int roleID)
    {
        bool inRole = false;
        int i = userRoles.GetLength(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(userRoles[j, 0]) == roleID)
            {
                inRole = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return inRole;
    }
```

TIA,
Chris

Comment: Weird ... I would debug this.

Comment: have you tried printing i and j inside the loop?

Comment: I'm embarrassingly unfamiliar with debugging C# classes used in ASP.NET pages. I'm not sure how I would go about printing i and j from inside a class.

Comment: Console.Write(i); should write i (when you're running the function, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you're not misdiagnosing the symptom, and that it really is getting stuck in the loop?  The code you have there doesn't look like wrong, my first thought would be that the place that you're calling IsInRole() isn't handling a 'false' return correctly.

Comment: Wow, after looking at this for 3 hours, I post the question, and then figure it out in less than 5 minutes. The loop is actually fine, as you suggested Tanzelax. it was the line after the loop that was wrong. I was using this code which will cause an infinite loop:

public int userID
    {
        get { return userID; }
        set { userID = value; }
    }

Man this is embarrasing. 

Sorry all, thanks for the help.
 - Chris

Comment: some code-standards would have saved you alot of trouble! prepend all internal fielsd with _ or m_ and use CamelCasing for all your public members. Then a bug like this would have been noticed in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Is j actually incrementing? or is it somehow being reset it back to 0?

Try this

```
public bool IsInRole(int roleID)
{
    bool inRole = false;
    int i = userRoles.GetLength(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        int k = j;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(userRoles[k, 0]) == roleID)
        {
            inRole = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return inRole;
}
```

Comment: change j++ to ++j ?  This makes no sense, there is nothing wrong with your code on it's face. I has to be something we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at MSDN's [GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) property, to quote '*An example of GetLength is GetLength(0), which returns the number of elements in the first dimension of the Array*.'

```
public bool IsInRole(int roleID)
    {
        bool inRole = false;
        try{
            int i = userRoles.GetLength(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
               if (Convert.ToInt32(userRoles[j, 0]) == roleID)
               {
                   inRole = true;
                   break;
               }
            }
        }catch(Exception up){
            throw up;
        }

        return inRole;
    }
```

I would be inclined to wrap the logic into a try/catch to see if the `Convert.ToInt32` or `GetLength(0)` is throwing an exception...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Ok! Man....wonder did anyone notice my exception block....Golly S.O. is such a +ive influence on my outlook on coding.... ;) LOL

Comment: Don't use 'throw up'. This will mess your stack trace. Just use 'throw'

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks solid so it must be not exiting for a different reason.  Could your array contain a value that would cause Convert.ToInt32 to hang or throw?